# DB2 nickname doesn't support decfloat type?

Tags: types, db2, db2-luw

I created a table with columns of datatype `decfloat`, but when I tried to create a federated nickname for this table like so:

```
CREATE SERVER CRV_TEST TYPE DB2/UDB VERSION '9.7' WRAPPER DRDA 
  AUTHORIZATION "XXX" PASSWORD "XXX" OPTIONS ( DBNAME   'XXX' ); 
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR DB2INST3 SERVER CRV_TEST 
  OPTIONS ( REMOTE_AUTHID   'xxx', REMOTE_PASSWORD  'xxx' ); 

CREATE NICKNAME xx.xx FOR CRV_TEST.xx.xx;
```

I got error as below:

> DB2 Database Error:
>
> ERROR [] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL3324N  Column "PAYMONEY" has a type of "DECFLOAT" which is not recognized.

My remote DB2 version is 9.7 and local is 9.5. Does anyone have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Full DDL of source and nickname? Else upgrade...

Comment: Is this a federated setup, by chance?

Comment: CREATE SERVER CRV_TEST
  TYPE DB2/UDB
  VERSION '9.7'
  WRAPPER DRDA
  AUTHORIZATION  "XXX"
  PASSWORD "XXX" 
  OPTIONS (
    DBNAME 'XXX'
    );

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR DB2INST3
  SERVER CRV_TEST
  OPTIONS (
    REMOTE_AUTHID 'xxx',
    REMOTE_PASSWORD 'xxx'
    );

CREATE NICKNAME xx.xx FOR CRV_TEST.xx.xx;

And then I got the error message: Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL3324N  Column "PAYMONEY" has a type of "DECFLOAT" which is not recognized.

Comment: So your remote server version is 9.7; what's the local server version?

Comment: local server version is 9.5

Comment: Can you try creating a simple table with a `DECFLOAT` column in your 9.5 database, not a nickname? Something like `create table test (f1 decfloat)`. Looks like 9.5 should support this data type. And make sure you're on the latest 9.5 fix pack.

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong with creating table with decfloat on the local DB of version 9.5

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this is actually [documented as a limitation of the federated wrapper](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002169.html) for version 9.5:

> The data source data types that correspond to the following DB2 data types are not supported by any of the wrappers: XML, DECFLOAT, structured types, and REF types.

Federation support in DB2 has sometimes lagged behind the engine development, which in this case itself does support `DECFLOAT`. If you are running the latest possible fix pack for DB2 9.5 and still get this error, looks like your only option is to upgrade to a newer DB2 version.

Comment: Could not log on stackoverflow for days. Thanks for all! I have change my data type to match the federation. There might be no way but to upgrade DB2 version.